# ngResource query with parametres

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am trying to get specific data from databases using angularJS query() method

```
note=notif.query({book_id: bk_id, user_id: u_id});
```

but wheen i test with

> console.log(note);

this is what i got as json data

```
[{"id":4,"user_id":8,"book_id":9,"like":true,"admin_id":1,"created_at":"2014-12-24T13:59:38.000Z","updated_at":"2014-12-24T13:59:38.000Z"},{"id":5,"user_id":8,"book_id":9,"like":true,"admin_id":1,"created_at":"2014-12-24T14:01:09.000Z","updated_at":"2014-12-24T14:01:09.000Z"},{"id":6,"user_id":8,"book_id":9,"like":true,"admin_id":1,"created_at":"2014-12-24T14:01:41.000Z","updated_at":"2014-12-24T14:01:41.000Z"},{"id":7,"user_id":8,"book_id":20,"like":true,"admin_id":1,"created_at":"2014-12-24T14:02:42.000Z","updated_at":"2014-12-24T14:02:42.000Z"}]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Open developer utils in browser and look at your request. I guess u pass book_id and user_id as request parameters, when server wants path variables...